# Does Google crawl page when G+ logo is embedded?

Tags: seo, robots.txt, pagerank, social-media

I have a `robots.txt` file in the root to prevent search engines indexing any of my sites. I have a social media management application embedded on my site that includes all major social media channels including G+.

I heard that once the G+ symbol is on a site Google will index sites despite having a `robots.txt` in the root. Is this true?

My thought behind locking out robots for a while is so I increase visitors per day first before allowing robots to crawl. Once I e.g. reach 100 visitors a day I will remove `robots.txt` file and will then receive a better initial page rank (in mind that PR is only updated every couple of months). Is this reasonable? How much emphasize is placed on the factor %visitor increase/day?

Comment: Remember to give Google ample time to add your G+ logo. Patience is a virtue!

Comment: Page rank is calculated on who links to you. It has nothing to do with amount or frequency of visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have many misconceptions about how search engines and ranking works, so I would suggest reading through the various Google help files. Google itself has an [SEO starter guide](http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf). To answer some basic points:

- PageRank is based purely on links to your site and nothing else.
- If your site is new then Googlebot will not be visiting very often anyway, so there is no reason to block it.
- The number of visitors to your site (or visitor increases) is **not a ranking factor at all**. Google cannot possibly know how many people are visiting your site besides the ones it sends directly.
- robots.txt prevents crawling of a page, but the URL [may appear in search results](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBdEwpRQRD0) under certain conditions.
- However as Stephen points out in his answer, Google may crawl URLs with Google+ buttons, even if they are blocked by robots.txt

Comment: You have robots.txt backwards.  It prevents crawling of your site but does not prevent indexing.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a Google +1 button on your page, Googlebot **will crawl** the page even if the page is blocked by `robots.txt`.  From the [Google+ Webmaster FAQ](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1140194):

> **Does +1 affect how Google crawls my site?**
>
> When you add the +1 button to a page, Google assumes that you want that page to be publicly available and visible in Google Search results. As a result, we may fetch and show that page even if it is disallowed in `robots.txt`.